# InvocationTargetException When Trying To Run a JavaFX Program

Tags: java, javafx

I just moved from Java 10.0.1 to Java 11 and I am trying to make a JavaFX application but for some reason, even with this simple code that all I am trying to do is load a TextArea to a scene and the scene to the stage. 
It gives me this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper (in unnamed module @0x84d43ff) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0x84d43ff
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)
    at core.Main.start(Main.java:20)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application core.Main
```

This is my code:

```
package core;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{

    TextArea textArea;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        textArea = new TextArea();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(textArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root , 300, 275);

        stage.setTitle("Interface-Editor");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I get a lot of errors like this when trying to do simple things like loading an FXML file to a stage but I don't really understand what the problem is.
I would really appreciate getting help with this.

Comment: Edit your question and post how are you running your application, and which are your VM options (`--module-path`, `--add-modules`)

Comment: It looks like you included a version of the `Control` class <= JavaFX 8, but use java(fx) >= 9 for the rest. For a proper JavaFX version structured using modules this line of the stacktrace: `at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)` would look like this: `at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)`

Comment: @febian, I don't really understand what I need to do or what you are trying to say at all.

Comment: @JoséPereda I also don't understand you, I tried running the commands you told me to run but it didn't work not in my project folder, src folder and core package.

Comment: If you are migrating to 11 you should definitely have a look at this site https://openjfx.io, and its documentation about getting started with [JavaFX 11](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs).

Comment: I know that it took months, BUT I simply managed to solve the problem by just using openjfx.io and changing some of the imports.