# JavaFX 11: IllegalAccessError when creating Label

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-11

This question is likely about the same issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600855/invocationtargetexception-when-trying-to-run-a-javafx-program), but it appears the asker of that one hasn't added enough information to receive a helpful response.

I am trying to run a JavaFx application with JDK and JavaFx SDK version 11.0.2.

This code works exactly as expected, producing an empty window:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 420, 420));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

However, if I try to add a label to the `StackPane`, an exception is thrown.

```java
import ...
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(new Label("42"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 420, 420));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The stack trace it produces looks like this (line 13 in Main is where the Label is created):

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper (in unnamed module @0xbbd2743) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0xbbd2743
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

I am running a recent version of IntelliJ Idea on Kubuntu. I downloaded the Oracle JDK as well as JavaFX, from the official websites

I put `javafx-sdk-11.0.2` in the directory `/usr/lib/jvm/` and `jdk-11.0.2` is in the same directory.

In IntelliJ Idea, I believe I have correctly chosen the JDK, and I have added `/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib` as a library.

IntelliJ Idea is using this command to launch the Application (split up for readability):

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java
  -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
  --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics
  --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED
  --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED
  -javaagent:/opt/jetbrains/idea-IU-183.4886.37/lib/idea_rt.jar=36031:/opt/jetbrains/idea-IU-183.4886.37/bin
  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
  -classpath
    /home/rm/IdeaProjects/JfxPlayground/out/production/JfxPlayground
    :/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/src.zip
    :/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx-swt.jar
    :/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.web.jar
    :/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.base.jar
    :/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.fxml.jar
    :/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.media.jar
    :/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.swing.jar
    :/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.controls.jar
    :/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.graphics.jar
  -p
    /usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.base.jar
    :/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.graphics.jar
  sample.Main
```

I have not modified any VM options.

How can I fix this error? Is it a bug in JavaFx?

Comment: When running with modules, you must not use `classpath` declaration, and vice versa.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are already giving an explanation of your issue:

> I have not modified any VM options.

Since JavaFX 11 is not part of the JDK anymore, you have to use the JavaFX SDK (as you are doing) from [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), or alternatively use Maven/Gradle to retrieve the JavaFX modules from Maven Central.

Then you need to add the SDK as a library, so IntelliJ can find the JavaFX classes.

But once you have done that, and given that the JavaFX jars are modules, you still need to do two things:

- Make the JavaFX modules available to your module-path
- Define which modules do you add to the project

Based on your IntelliJ output, it is adding by default `javafx.graphics` and `javafx.base`:

```
--add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics

-p /usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.base.jar
:/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.graphics.jar
```

(note that `-p` is the same as `--module-path`)

This explains why your project runs in the first case, when you don't have a control added to the scene, just the `StackPane`, that belongs to the `javafx.graphics` [module](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html), but fails with the posted exception when you add the `Label`, that belongs to the `javafx.controls` [module](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Label.html).

This has been said a number of times: you *need* to set the required VM options for your project.

Start by reading the documentation at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/, including the [IntelliJ](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij) doc, section Non-modular projects for your IDE. And read the part 4. Add VM options.

[image: VM Options]

So click on Run -> Edit Configurations, and add:

```
-p /usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls
```

Apply, and run, the issue will be solved.

Comment: is there a way to do the same thing without specifying VM options?

Comment: @user2914191Execute `javafx:run` from the Maven window.

Comment: Instead of downloading the JavaFX SDK or libraries, another option is using a JDK that includes the JavaFX/OpenJFX libraries. At least two such products: *LibericaFX* from BellSoft, and the *JDK FX* builds of *Azul Platform Core* from Azul Systems.

Answer (score 0):

I would use gradle and the javafx plugin for that.

```
apply plugin: "org.openjfx.javafxplugin"

javafx {
    version = "11"
    modules = ["javafx.base", "javafx.controls", "javafx.graphics"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be useful, especially if you planning to package your application as fat-jar.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57691362/11051553).

Instead of modifying vm options you can create another `Main` class which does not extend `javafx.application.Application` and call your application start method from there. Try the following:

```java
public class App extends Application
{

    @Override public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        // all the stuff necessary
    }

    // Method called "main" here for experimental purposes.
    // But for production use you may decide to call it, "run" for example.
    // Exact name does not matter.
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        App.launch();
    }

}
```

```java
// This class must NOT extend Application. It is a wrapper only.
public class Runner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Starter method from previous class
        App.main(args);
    }
}
```

Trying to run `App.main()` with default configuration (`VM options` is an empty field) would cause an error, while `Runner.main()` executes successfully.

For deeper understanding you may compare the java run commands (idea folds them by default) found in Run or Debug windows.

Answer (score -3):

check your JAVA_HOME,
JAVA_HOME'version must be jdk9+ or jdk11+