# Build executable JAR with JavaFX11 from maven

Tags: maven, java-11, javafx-11

I've made a Java app which uses Maven, JavaFX and some other dependencies.
Before, it was easy to build an executable jar but since Java11 is modular and does not include JavaFX i just can't build a working one.

I've already tried a lot of things but i don't know what i'm supposed to do now.

My pom.xml

```xml
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>out/</outputDirectory>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>fr.crosf32.fxtest.Entry</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I've tried to build artifact with all dependencies inside but i obtain an error when i run (java -jar ):

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at fr.crosf32.fxtest.SlimForest.lambda$new$0(SlimForest.java:26)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 11 more
```

EDIT

I've tried to build a jar which contains JavaFX using Jlink but when i try to run the app i obtain :

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        ... 1 more
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Did you have a look here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven

Comment: Yes i did, but the repo is missing. (javafx-maven-plugin) so i can't use it.

Comment: I found another one in com.zenjava but when i run jfx:run it throws ```Could not find artifact javafx-packager:javafx-packager:jar:1.8.0_20 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1/../lib/ant-javafx.jar"```

Comment: What do you mean with the "repo is missing"? You can use the `javafx-maven-plugin` to run JavaFX projects and also to use `jlink`. See the referred documentation and also the plugin's readme: https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#usage.

Comment: Ok sorry, i got the javafx-maven-plugin. i can run javafx:compile and javafx:run well but javafx:jlink gives me an error : ```Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.2:jlink (default-cli) on project ay-simforest: Error: jlink requires a module descriptor```

Comment: That means that your project is not modular (yet). You'll need to add `module-info.java`, with the required modules.

Comment: Actually i did. ```module simforest {
    requires java.base;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires java.sql;
    requires javafx.controls;

    opens simforest;
}``` but it still gives me this error. I put the module-info at the root of the project which seems to be normal..

Comment: I still have the issue.. (Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.2:jlink (default-cli) on project ay-simforest: Error: jlink requires a module descriptor) there is a module-info.java though

Comment: Can you edit your question and post enough details so we can reproduce your issue? Otherwise it is hard to say. At least your module-info and the project structure?

Comment: First, the openjfx maven example referred to by the first comment is useless.  It's a hello world example, and certainly not going to help anyone figure out how to make a real pom file for a real JavaFx application.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I struggled through the process of creating an executable jar as well, but this workaround is what worked for me, and I hope it works for you as well:

First of all, instead of using the `jar` plugin, I used the `shade` plugin in `pom.xml`, which creates a "fat jar" or "uber jar" that contains your classes and all of the dependencies within the jar. This way, your jar will be included with all the necessary `javafx` packages and classes. That is, if you include these in the `<dependencies>` section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

... or whatever else of the `javafx` libraries you need in order for your application to run.

Simply doing this does not work, however. I'm assuming that your main class `Entry extends Application`?

I'm guessing the `jar` needs to know the *actual Main class* that **does not** extend Application, so I just created another Main class called `SuperMain` (it was only a temporary name) that *calls my original main class*, which is `Main`:

```
// package <your.package.name.here>

public class SuperMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

whereas in your case it's `Entry`.

So in my pom.xml, I have a plugin called `shade` that looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>my.package.name.SuperMain</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and there should be a jar that's "shaded" after you execute `mvn package`.

Thanks to the answer to this post: [JavaFX 11 : Create a jar file with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569724/javafx-11-create-a-jar-file-with-gradle/52571719#)

Hope this helps!

Comment: you are a MASTERMIND, I was struggling with this for DAYS :)

Comment: But wait I get that pipeline error when trying to run a jar in different OS. For instance if I compile in windows, that jar gives me issues running in Mac OS. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @darthgamer64 Sorry I can't be of any help. I haven't built a cross-platform jar file before so that doesn't sound familiar to me--although it should work in theory. Did you ever figure out what the issue is? One guess I have is because the Mac you're trying to run it on doesn't have JRE installed?

Comment: And after finishing this brilliant guideline, add the additional configuration mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743609/9492722) to the shade plugin to avoid __"SecurityException: Invalid signature"__ error.

Answer (score 1):

even if it´s a long time ago but maybe there are some other guys searching for this answer: you have to include os classifier in your pom.xml here is an excellent tutorial for this:

https://youtu.be/w_PsCNqqcE4?list=PL4h6ypqTi3RR_bhBk6PtLfD83YkaJXXxw

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30195634)