# Build executable .jar by Maven with depending on JavaFX

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jar

everyone!

I've tried to create `.jar` file by Maven with dependence on JavaFX according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019143/build-executable-jar-with-javafx11-from-maven). Unfortunately, attempts was failed. In folder `targets` creating two files:

- MAVEN_UI_INTRO-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- original-MAVEN_UI_INTRO-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  With first file, I get this error:
  `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`
  With second file, this error:
  `no main manifest attribute, in target/original-MAVEN_UI_INTRO-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Build by command `mvn clean package`

Start by command `java -jar target/"someJarFile.jar"`

Main question: What do I wrong?

UPD: My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.novalab</groupId>
    <artifactId>MAVEN_UI_INTRO</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.novalab.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.novalab.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Duplicated of the question [Maven Shade JavaFX runtime components are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing)