# Creating Windows Executable for OpenJFX 11 Project in Eclipse with Maven Integration

Tags: eclipse, maven, javafx, openjdk-11

I'm switching over from Java 8 (Oracle JDK) to OpenJDK 11 and OpenJFX 11. I've successfully gotten my project to work in Eclipse through Maven via the `clean javafx:run` command using the `maven-compiler-plugin` however I am having issues building a runnable jar and windows executable. I do not need a linux or mac runnable as this project is just an internal product and we only use windows.

I have already tried several plugins such as the `maven-shade-plugin` and also tried running `mvm package` to no avail. I've tried this [Build executable JAR with JavaFX11 from maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019143/build-executable-jar-with-javafx11-from-maven) and this [How to deploy a JavaFX 11 Desktop application with a JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-11-desktop-application-with-a-jre).

In the past I could just build a executable jar through Eclipse's "Export Runnable Jar" option and then creating an executable through launch4j, however this does not seem to work anymore and I understand this probably due to the modular structure of OpenJDk 9+.

I have all the JavaFX dependencies added as well as the JAXB ones that I needed and it runs in the IDE when I build it (although I can't get it to run as a Java Application Run Configuration once I made it run in Maven Run Configuration.

Here are my plugins:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.tapestry.testertools.ApplicationMainFrame</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.tapestry.testertools.ApplicationMainFrame</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                 </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Here is the error message when i attempt to run `mvn clean package`

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.325 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-20T09:19:35-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project testertools: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --module-path -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: The issue appears to be "_Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --module-path_". This indicates Maven is using Java 8 or earlier. Make sure you have Java 11 installed and that your environment variables (i.e. PATH, JAVA_HOME) point to it.

Comment: This was the issue. I still had JRE 8 installed on my machine so the run configuration was defaulting to that. Many thanks.