# Exporting JavaFX Project with Maven (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I've been struggling with this for the past few hours, and I can't seem to find a way to export this properly.

Error: Could not find or load main class me.mrbakbuki.app.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Relevant part from my pom.xml file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>gui.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>me.mrbakbuki.app.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I want to export this as an executable jar file
Any help appreciated

Comment: You need to add a classifier for the OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build executable JAR with JavaFX11 from maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019143/build-executable-jar-with-javafx11-from-maven)

Answer (score -1):

You need to run your jar with Java 8 because it comes with JavaFX. I had the same problem a while ago and running the jar with Java 8 solved it for me.

Comment: Downgrading java version is not a solution.