# Maven-assembly-plugin creates empty (1KB or 2KB) jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I'd like to create a runnable/executable jar using maven's assembly plugin using the assembly:single goal. (I'm using Eclipse and Java 8, Maven 4) However, only an empty, small size jar created (1 KB or sometimes 2KB) in the target folder.
My pom.xml is the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging> <!-- Added !!!! -->
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Added !!!! Goal assembly:single -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>controller.Start</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--  -->

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What do you get if you run mvn package?

Comment: assembly plugin will ignore test scope dependencies by default. Other than that do you have any classes or resources that should be included or is your src/main folder empty?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli In Eclipse, I clicked on build and gave the goal "package". After, I checked the targer folder and I saw that the jar is bigger now 20KB. On double click, the jar does nothing. I tried to run the jar in console as follows: java -jar Sample.jar I received the following error: no main manifest attribute... After, I opened the jar with WinRAR and added the following line to the manifest file: Main-Class: controller.Start After, I tried to run again, but it gave another error...

Comment: @SimonMartinelli The error is the following: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Thend\eclipse-workspace\Sample\target\src\main\java\view\Sample.fxml accordingly, it doesn't find the fxml file...so my fxml loader looks like this: URL url = new File("src/main/java/view/Sample.fxml").toURI().toURL(); BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(url);

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I would like to add everything, do you suggest to use maven-shade-plugin?

Comment: You cannot load a file like this because it will be packaged in a JAR where the path is differnet

Comment: What are you trying to do? JavaFX?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes, I would like to run a JavaFX app from a jar, only by double clicking on the jar :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build executable JAR with JavaFX11 from maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019143/build-executable-jar-with-javafx11-from-maven)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli This is not the same problem at all. Please do not mark as a duplicate. This is a Java 8 (jdk 1.8) project, JavaFX is completely different after Java 9 I have no problem in case of Java 11+ (in other project I use JavaFX with Java18 without a problem)