Maven can't find the mainClass, even though it's defined. The manifest file isn't being generated, or can't be found (or includes down to nothing)
When I package my JavaFX application, java can't find the manifest file. In the Pom.xml, the main-class is definitely defined, so I have no idea what's going on. I've defined the main-class with this: <mainClass>me.jason.badddos.Application</mainClass>
Clean > Package > Output:

https://pastebin.com/AmzCA2qk


When I try to run it:
java -jar BadDDOS-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
no main manifest attribute, in BadDDOS-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Jar -tf:
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
me/
me/jason/
me/jason/badddos/
me/jason/badddos/css/
me/jason/badddos/fxml/
me/jason/badddos/misc/
me/jason/badddos/skins/
me/jason/badddos/Application.class
me/jason/badddos/css/home-style.css
me/jason/badddos/DDOS.class
me/jason/badddos/fxml/home-view.fxml
me/jason/badddos/Home_Controller.class
me/jason/badddos/misc/shrek.jpg
me/jason/badddos/skins/ddosBtn_Skin.class
module-info.class
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/me.jason/
META-INF/maven/me.jason/BadDDOS/
META-INF/maven/me.jason/BadDDOS/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/me.jason/BadDDOS/pom.properties

I opened up the packaged jar, and found the manifest file. 
this is kind of obvious, but the main-class is missing, despite me adding the main-class somewhere inside the Pom.xml
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.8.5
Built-By: Jason
Build-Jdk: 21.0.2

POM.XML
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>me.jason</groupId>
  <artifactId>BadDDOS</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>BadDDOS</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.akman/jpackage-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.akman</groupId>
      <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
      <version>11.1.2</version>
    </dependency><dependency>
      <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
      <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
      <version>12.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>21</source>
          <target>21</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>me.jason.badddos.Application</mainClass>
              <launcher>app</launcher>
              <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
              <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
              <noManPages>true</noManPages>
              <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
              <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>


What is the actual error message? Post it in its entirety, formatted as code if it is more than a single line. How are you running the application?

Off-topic: why do you think "packaged jar files" should be called "compiled"? Class files are the result of compilation. Jar files are the result of packaging class files, and other resources (which are not compiled) into an archive.

@James_D I'm used to calling something that is built as a standalone or into an executable "compiled"

That's not standard use of the word. "Compilation" is the process of automatically parsing source code and translating it into language the machine understands (e.g. machine code, or in this case bytecode, which is understandable by the virtual machine). Simply bundling various files into a zip file (a jar file is just a zip file) is not compilation. Anyway, please clarify the question.

@James_D Thanks, I didn't know that - I redid the post

Remove the dependency maven-shade-plugin that does not make sense...

@khmarbaise it packs all the dependencies into one jar, and makes it a standalone. I tested without it, it's not causing the problem

What are the contents of the jar file? You can see these by running jar -tf BadDDOS-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar from the command line. Generally, the strategy of creating an "uber-jar" like this is not really supported for JavaFX. The preferred way is to create a native bundle, using something like jpackage. See the "packaging" section of the tag wiki

C:\Users\Jason\IdeaProjects\BadDDOS\target>java jar -tf BadDDOS-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jar```

I'll remove the shade plugin and replace it with jPackage - but it will still give the same error without the shade plugin

Can you run the command I suggested, without the additional java prepended to it?

do you have a link that you use for the jpackage plugin, I found the dependency, but I can't find the plugin for the pom.xml

@James_D Sorry, I had to add it to the path - it's on the post now

Apart from the lack of a defined main class, the jar file only has your code in it.  So, none of the dependent code exists and even if you set the main class correctly it would not run unless you add the dependent code to the classpath or module path.  Your app includes a module-info, so it should be run as a module, and -jar doesn't do that, it runs stuff from the classpath not the modulepath.

Your JavaFX Maven plugin is already configured to create a jlink zip.  But the main class in the plugin configuration should include your module name, like the linked example.  I advise you don't try to package your application as a runnable jar, and instead run mvn javafx:jlink goal to create a zip of your app and distribute that instead (the link I provided has instructions on how to do that).

Just in case you are using a non modular project: This repo contains a simple preconfigured project, which builds a fat/uber JAR with the Maven goal "package": https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxAppMavenNonModular

@crjase The packaging is being done by the javafx-maven-plugin and not by the maven-shade-plugin. So you should remove the maven-shade-plugin and keep only the javafx-maven-plugin which will package it, apart from that using a dependency to a maven plugin is simply wrong.

I took out the shade plugin, what should I do to package it? I don't care about any of the uber or standalone packagers like shade, as long as it can find the main class
Right now my main-class is in the javafx configuration, and I don't know where to put it if that's not the right spot

I updated the pom.xml
I run maven clean, then maven package. That's all I do. I don't know what to do next though, because the main-class attribute is ghosting me

You are not following the advice of comments (use jlink and not an executable jar).  But, regardless, here is a link to a related question Build executable JAR with JavaFX11 from maven which shows how you can use Maven to define a main class for a jar artifact.  See also Maven adding mainClass in pom.xml.  As noted earlier, even if you do that you will likely have other issues.

Also, you can specify the main class for execution in the command line, it does not need to be in the manifest.

I made a jlink zip, but there's no executable. I'll try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019143/build-executable-jar-with-javafx11-from-maven out. What I'm trying to do is create an executable, standalone if I can. I'll lookup some stuff to do with the jlink zip, because I know it's not useless, I just can't find the executable...

So I have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019143/build-executable-jar-with-javafx11-from-maven working. You should post what you said as an asnwer so I can mark it as complete. I'll mess with the JLink later on, thanks for everyone's help.
