# Cannot resolve symbol 'StackPane' Intelij IDEA

Tags: java, javafx

I tried to run this code in intelij IDE, but it shows an error, `java: cannot find symbol, symbol:   class StackPane`

But when I tried the same code on Netbeans IDE, it worked well. what could be the reason for that?

```
package javafxfirstproject;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFxFirstProject extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you actually added the JavaFX library to your classpath in IntelliJ?

Comment: yes I did so. but still having a warning `java: warning: source release 11 requires target release 11`.   I'm using java 1.8 version. Is that the problem?

Comment: You didn't think to include that in your original question? Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how best to use Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -2):

You should follow Intellij IDEA JavaFX [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html), especially [Adding the JavaFX library](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#add-javafx-lib) and [Add VM options](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#vm-options).

Here is [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291958/javafx-11-illegalaccesserror-when-creating-label) with simillar issue.

Go through this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn2tbftFjno), your code works on my computer after completing this tutorial.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have added both javaFX library and VM options but still having the same issue.

Comment: Check this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn2tbftFjno).

Comment: I updated my java `version 1.8` to `version 11` and then followed the tutorial. And now it is working. Thank you very much for your support.